# How do I resolve springframework no suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am new to java/spring and I am writing an app using spring framework

but I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysl://localhost/java_test
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1025)
    at com.oshabz.lesson5.config.Repositories.ProductRepository.addProduct(ProductRepository.java:15)
    at com.oshabz.lesson5.config.Services.ProductService.addOneProduct(ProductService.java:15)
    at com.oshabz.lesson4.App.main(App.java:17)
```

Maven dependencies

The maven dependencies gets the jdbc, mysql-connector

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.15</version>  
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>   
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>   
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>  
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.15</version>    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Project Config

I did the context configuration on the projectConfig file

I also configured the jdbc configuration.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.oshabz.lesson5.config.Repositories", "com.oshabz.lesson5.config.Services"})
public class ProjectConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        var dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysl://localhost/java_test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
     
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The error in your question title does not match the error in your question (_"No suitable driver found for jdbc:**mysl**://..."_ vs _"no suitable driver found for jdbc:**mysql**"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the connection string (**mysl**):

It should be:

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_test");
```

Answer (score 0):

change the connection string to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
```

add the following in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The OP already has a dependency for `mysql-connector-java` in their POM.

Answer (score 0):

you have write wrong url:

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_test");
```

and make sure to write dependency with suitable version of mysql in your server:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>version_of_mysql</version>
```

Comment: The OP already has a dependency for mysql-connector-java in their POM.